# Push notification using expo when app is killed/closed

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I understand that there are many similar question on stack overflow. I have been hunting google from last week, but did not get to conclusion yet. I'hv gone through almost of them. It has become really annoying for my clients.

I'm working on expo managed workflow app and trying to send push notification using expo push token. I have also added google-services.json for firebase.  I'm following expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/)

1. When expo client is open - *notification received*
2. When expo client is in background - *notification received*
3. When expo client is killed/closed - **not receiving**

I have build standalone app (apk)

1. When app is open - *notification received*
2. When app is in background - *notification received*
3. When app is killed/closed - **not receiving**

So to check, I have manually switched on AutoStart for this app from setting and it works perfectly fine in all states.

My questions here are -

1. Can we receive notification without adding app to AutoStart when app
   is killed? How? (I have googled and found that we cannot
   programatically add app to AutoStart)
2. If not AutoStart, what else could be the work around to receive
   notification when app is killed? Can we build some background
   services to do so?

Any guide, help documentation or example will be appreciated.

I'll avoid ejecting expo app since there are many expo dependencies I have used.
I have also found that expo cannot be used without ejecting with firebase or OneSignal.

Comment: You can create a `SyncAdapter` which periodically runs and check if there are pending messages/notifications in the server

Comment: Can we force put the app in background when it is killed? I mean can we automatically restart the app after it is killed with some background worker in react native/ expo?

Comment: No, you can't do that, killing or background the app is a system "decision"

Comment: I understand. Is expo having problem with push notification or react native project cannot run background notifications? I'm ejecting my app and trying with only firebase or OneSignal. Lets see what works. What could be better, fcm or OneSignal or are there anything else that I may be missing?

Comment: I tried Expo, OneSignal &  react-native-firebase and found that expo does not every time sends message, it drops many a times and does not send at all when app is killed. OneSignal & firebase both deliver the notification all time. Both are same. One question arises is that how is OneSignal different from fcm when it itself uses fcm for sending notification?

Comment: I don't know OneSignal or Expo, but probably OneSignal internally has more reliability than using the FMC base Service. WhatsApp and Facebook use a SyncAdapter, I think they are using it as "backup" when push notification fail to reach the device if the app is killed. SyncAdapter it's not "realtime" but it is better to receive a notification with an acceptable delay than not receiving it at all.